how to type gujarati in text in textbox using html and css fornt family
I have one textbox in html from. typing google gujarati font typing in textbox. but not any solution. so please get solution.
to type Gujarati text in an HTML text box using a specific font family, you need to set up your HTML and CSS accordingly. Here's a step-by-step guide to achieve this:
Choose a Gujarati Font: You can use Google Fonts or any other font source that supports Gujarati script. For example, Google Fonts offers "Noto Sans Gujarati".
Include the Font in Your HTML: Use the link tag to include the font in your HTML document.
Apply the Font to the Text Box: Use CSS to set the font family for your text box.
Here's a complete example:
this code not use.

Please show us what you have tried.
